# Connect to an Oracle DB with sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

My backend system is connecting to a remote Oracle DB via datasource :

```
dataSource_esb {

    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    url : jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/test
    username : username
    password : password

}
```

Now I am trying to connect to this DB via sqldeveloper, but I am not able to connect. Below is sqldeveloper configuration :

- connection name : test
- username : username
- password : password
- connection type : basic
- role : default
- hostname : x.x.x.x
- port : 1521
- SID  : -
- service    name : test

Answer (score 1):

Database `test` should be in `SID` instead of `service name`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your data base URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/test
jdbc:oracle:thin is your driver type
@x.x.x.x:1521 is port Number
Then instead of /test there should be :test if test is your data base SID in configuration.
Hope you understood

Thanks
Basanta